# strong, weak, and id

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I did some `iOS` development back when iOS 3.0 came out, but for two years I lost track of how iOS was doing.

I remember that you would do retain back in `iOS` 3.0 and even so, I still don't remember exactly what the reason for retaining in a setter was. This is just the one thing that is stumping me so far.

And last but not least there's the idea that local variables are strong by default in iOS 5 with ARC. How can they be strong if some of them don't have setters? (As an example, id.)

Some code to explain what I mean:

```
+(double) popOperandOffStack:(NSMutableArray *) stack{
    double result = 0;

    id topOfStack = [stack lastObject];
```

`// how is topOfStack retaining [stack lastObject] if it's simply id?`

```
    if (topOfStack) [stack removeLastObject];

    if ([topOfStack isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]){
        result = [topOfStack doubleValue];
    }
    else if ([topOfStack isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){

        if ([topOfStack isEqualToString:@"+"]){
            result = [self popOperandOffStack:stack] + [self popOperandOffStack:stack];
        }

        if ([topOfStack isEqualToString:@"-"]){
            result = [self popOperandOffStack:stack] - [self popOperandOffStack:stack];
        }

        if ([topOfStack isEqualToString:@"*"]){
            result = [self popOperandOffStack:stack] * [self popOperandOffStack:stack];
        }

        if ([topOfStack isEqualToString:@"/"]){
            result = [self popOperandOffStack:stack] / [self popOperandOffStack:stack];
        }


    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: With ARC, you can program without thinking about retain/autorelease/release. Only need to care about that to give the correct strong/weak attribute for the ivars and implicit ivar created by property declaration.

Comment: Can you explain it a little better? I don't get what you mean. The second sentence.

Comment: What do you mean by "if some of them don't have setters"?

Comment: topOfStack is holding onto another object and is left holding onto it past it being removed from the NSMutableArray. How is it doing it if it is simply of type id? Does an id variable have a setter method behind the scenes?

Answer (score 2):

You can send messages to objects without knowing their exact type at compile time. In fact, you routinely do that when you send messages to objects that you get back from arrays: you do not need to cast `id` to the exact type, you can simply send a message, and Objective C will dispatch it correctly. The only exception to this rule is accessing properties with the dot `.` syntax: you do need a cast there.

Every object whose class inherits from `NSObject` responds to `retain`, `release`, `autorelease`, and so on. This is all that the ARC needs to know. In the worst case you will get "an object does not respond to selector" message if an `id` that you have happens to point to something invalid.

Comment: "and Objective C will dispatch it correctly" - assuming that the compiler picks the right method signature, of course!

Comment: @tc. Wait, I thought the compiler's guess about the signature is there to issue an error or a warning, and the compiler could be wrong about it. But as far as the runtime dispatch goes, when the signature is fixed at compile time, the compiler is out of the loop: an object either repponds to a selector, or it does not. If it does not, an exception is thrown.

Comment: If there are two methods (in different classes) with identical selectors but incompatible method signatures, but the compiler only knows about one of them (because you didn't #include the header of the other), it will not issue a warning.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be confusing properties with instance variables and local variables.

**Variables do not have setters.** Properties have setters. Properties of **any type** can have setters (except possibly void). Instance variables might *happen to* correspond to properties, but the variables themselves do not have "setters". `obj->ivar` will never call a setter, **not even under ARC**.

ARC simply does approximately three things:

1. Insert `retain`, `release`, `autorelease`, and `dealloc` for you. When you write

   ```
   // ARC
   {
     id foo = [array lastObject];
     ...
   }
   ```

   it gets translated to approximately

   ```
   // MRC
   {
     id foo = [[array lastObject] retain];
     ...
     [foo release];
   }
   ```

   It uses Objective-C naming conventions to figure out what it needs to retain and release. There are a few optimizations (it *actually* uses `objc_retain()` and friends for reasons described in the [ARC spec](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html), plus a few more functions to handle autoreleased objects more efficiently than `-autorelease`.)
2. Release `__strong` ivars in `-dealloc` for you. It does not call the property setters; it just releases the ivars. It might also set them to `nil`.
3. Zeroing weak references.`__weak` variables are read/written with `objc_copyWeak()` and friends instead of being accessed directly. There's additionally a hook in `-[NSObject release]` (or so) in order to implement zeroing weak references correctly.

Additionally, the semantics surrounding blocks and `__block` variables are changed in a way that isn't easy to replicate via MRC. Apart from that, I believe everything ARC does can be replicated by calling the ARC runtime support function calls.

The only connection between ARC and setters is that you can get rid of a lot of properties, because the compiler inserts retain/release on ivar access.

Comment: But isn't the 'strong' property keyword used as a synonym for retain in iOS 5? If you could please clear this. I'm guessing that they are two different things.

Comment: In *properties*, yes, but only in properties, and that has nothing to do with ARC — you can use `@property (strong)` without using ARC. I think they changed the naming so it contrasts with `weak`.